# Python при запуске программы выдаёт вот это Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: python, pycharm

Переустанавливал Pycharm и Python, не помогает.

Comment: Запустите вашу программу из консоли/терминала/CMD `python main.py`, что вы получаете?

Comment: Запускается спокойно.

Comment: но в Pycharm не запускается.

Comment: А что если проблема в запускаемом коде?

Comment: нет с кодом проблемы нет 100%

Comment: с библиотеками проблема!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону виртуального окружения.
Pycharm при создании проекта создает свое виртуальное окружение в папке venv проекта, в котором может не быть требуемых библиотек и модулей.
Либо доустановить нужные модули либо использовать стандартное окружение.
При создании проекта развернуть меню Project interpreter: и выбрать пункт Existing Interpreter, вместо New Environment usig ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]